# how to read the below kml file in php?

Tags: php

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name></name>
        <Placemark>
            <name></name>
            <description><![CDATA[description: <br><br>WardId: 4<br>Shape_Leng: 7103.25259602000<br>Shape_Le_1: 7103.25259602000<br>Shape_Area: 1374396.12779999990]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#poly-FFFFFF-1-76</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name='description'>
                    <value></value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='ULBName'>
                    <value></value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='WardId'>
                    <value>4</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Shape_Leng'>
                    <value>7103.25259602000</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Shape_Le_1'>
                    <value>7103.25259602000</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Shape_Area'>
                    <value>1374396.12779999990</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                        <coordinates>74.993243,15.488983,0.0 74.99246,15.489756,0.0 74.992439,15.488891,0.0 74.992614,15.488423,0.0 74.992705,15.487784000000001,0.0 74.992835,15.487309999999999,0.0 74.992879,15.486597999999999,0.0 74.992903,15.486198000000002,0.0 74.993204,15.485721000000002,0.0 74.993615,15.485400000000002,0.0 74.993974,15.485028999999997,0.0 74.994503,15.484024,0.0 74.994763,15.483179000000002,0.0 74.995571,15.482164999999998,0.0 74.99618,15.481296000000002,0.0 74.996778,15.480464,0.0 74.997053,15.480071000000002,0.0 74.99758900000002,15.478965000000002,0.0 74.997966,15.478071,0.0 74.998122,15.477612000000002,0.0 74.998578,15.476816,0.0 74.998876,15.475947,0.0 74.998887,15.475911,0.0 74.998978,15.475445999999996,0.0 74.999091,15.475168,0.0 74.999163,15.474965,0.0 74.99934,15.474301,0.0 74.999432,15.473543,0.0 74.999474,15.473187999999999,0.0 74.999637,15.472535,0.0 74.999756,15.472109000000001,0.0 74.99968,15.471658999999999,0.0 74.999646,15.471458,0.0 74.999566,15.470972,0.0 74.99978,15.47094,0.0 74.999713,15.470204,0.0 74.999676,15.469762999999999,0.0 74.999669,15.469649,0.0 75.000343,15.469477000000005,0.0 75.000386,15.467789999999997,0.0 75.001133,15.468036,0.0 75.001824,15.468117999999999,0.0 75.001876,15.467829000000002,0.0 75.002009,15.466991000000002,0.0 75.002342,15.466923000000001,0.0 75.002689,15.466886000000004,0.0 75.003081,15.466824,0.0 75.00374100000002,15.466632999999998,0.0 75.004185,15.466250999999996,0.0 75.00425,15.46577,0.0 75.004122,15.46541,0.0 75.003779,15.465175,0.0 75.00412,15.464468999999996,0.0 75.004419,15.464796,0.0 75.00495,15.464961,0.0 75.005435,15.465155000000001,0.0 75.005896,15.46541,0.0 75.00613000000001,15.465639,0.0 75.006463,15.466240000000003,0.0 75.006823,15.466719999999999,0.0 75.007094,15.467111,0.0 75.007373,15.467509999999999,0.0 75.008011,15.467647000000001,0.0 75.008061,15.467647000000001,0.0 75.00812400000001,15.468452999999998,0.0 75.008141,15.469336,0.0 75.00763,15.470072,0.0 75.007137,15.47082,0.0 75.006886,15.471011999999998,0.0 75.006409,15.471315,0.0 75.006011,15.471806000000003,0.0 75.005672,15.472582999999998,0.0 75.005507,15.473005,0.0 75.005142,15.473607999999997,0.0 75.004826,15.474166000000002,0.0 75.00473,15.474329000000001,0.0 75.004472,15.475067,0.0 75.004179,15.475801,0.0 75.003901,15.476478,0.0 75.003584,15.47724,0.0 75.003479,15.477498999999996,0.0 75.003011,15.478221999999999,0.0 75.002195,15.479398,0.0 75.001887,15.479836,0.0 75.00113,15.480661,0.0 75.000471,15.481472,0.0 74.99978,15.482393000000004,0.0 74.999277,15.483463,0.0 74.9989,15.483996,0.0 74.998416,15.48446,0.0 74.997055,15.485603000000003,0.0 74.996053,15.486444999999996,0.0 74.994457,15.487810999999999,0.0 74.993243,15.488983,0.0</coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name></name>
            <description><![CDATA[description: <br>ULBName: <br>WardId: 7<br>Shape_Leng: 5020.58225189000<br>Shape_Le_1: 5020.58225189000<br>Shape_Area: 1068302.69824999990]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#poly-FFFFFF-1-76</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name='description'>
                    <value></value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='ULBName'>
                    <value></value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='WardId'>
                    <value>7</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Shape_Leng'>
                    <value>5020.58225189000</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Shape_Le_1'>
                    <value>5020.58225189000</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Shape_Area'>
                    <value>1068302.69824999990</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                        <coordinates>75.02649,15.469437999999998,0.0 75.026515,15.469663000000002,0.0 75.026304,15.470367,0.0 75.026349,15.470820999999997,0.0 75.026183,15.471789000000001,0.0 75.025811,15.473340999999996,0.0 75.027386,15.474036,0.0 75.027359,15.474757999999998,0.0 75.027474,15.474835,0.0 75.027275,15.475308999999998,0.0 75.027236,15.476292000000003,0.0 75.027293,15.47772,0.0 75.025557,15.477613,0.0 75.024157,15.477534000000002,0.0 75.022646,15.477439000000002,0.0 75.021019,15.477343000000001,0.0 75.020905,15.477070999999997,0.0 75.020736,15.47664,0.0 75.020603,15.476312000000002,0.0 75.02015,15.4752,0.0 75.019859,15.474506,0.0 75.019541,15.473855,0.0 75.019164,15.473109999999998,0.0 75.018845,15.472477,0.0 75.018487,15.471779,0.0 75.018103,15.471041,0.0 75.017942,15.470742000000003,0.0 75.01803,15.470278,0.0 75.017949,15.469809999999997,0.0 75.017876,15.469402,0.0 75.017881,15.468906999999996,0.0 75.017354,15.469003,0.0 75.016746,15.469030999999996,0.0 75.016084,15.468434999999996,0.0 75.015589,15.467982,0.0 75.015266,15.467591000000002,0.0 75.014416,15.4666,0.0 75.014105,15.466134999999998,0.0 75.013931,15.465893,0.0 75.014657,15.465376,0.0 75.015267,15.464979000000001,0.0 75.015429,15.464926000000002,0.0 75.01557400000002,15.464778999999997,0.0 75.015748,15.464669,0.0 75.01596100000002,15.464483000000003,0.0 75.016017,15.464439,0.0 75.01605500000001,15.464410000000003,0.0 75.016089,15.464384000000003,0.0 75.016129,15.464352,0.0 75.016168,15.464322000000003,0.0 75.016206,15.464292000000004,0.0 75.016251,15.464257,0.0 75.016293,15.464226000000002,0.0 75.016332,15.464197,0.0 75.016398,15.464143999999997,0.0 75.016685,15.463924,0.0 75.01677,15.463857000000003,0.0 75.016788,15.463843,0.0 75.016849,15.463924,0.0 75.016919,15.464021,0.0 75.01694,15.464050000000002,0.0 75.016961,15.464075000000001,0.0 75.017007,15.464140000000004,0.0 75.017057,15.464206999999998,0.0 75.017144,15.464325999999998,0.0 75.017321,15.464365,0.0 75.017422,15.464388000000003,0.0 75.017533,15.464412999999999,0.0 75.017766,15.464465,0.0 75.018056,15.464544999999996,0.0 75.018133,15.464567999999998,0.0 75.018274,15.464633000000001,0.0 75.018477,15.464728999999998,0.0 75.018585,15.464784,0.0 75.018845,15.464859,0.0 75.019228,15.464975999999998,0.0 75.019547,15.465077,0.0 75.019582,15.465134,0.0 75.019637,15.465222000000002,0.0 75.019679,15.46529,0.0 75.019727,15.465370000000002,0.0 75.01978,15.465456000000001,0.0 75.019804,15.465566,0.0 75.019825,15.465695000000002,0.0 75.019856,15.465864999999999,0.0 75.01988,15.465990000000001,0.0 75.019896,15.466067,0.0 75.01991000000001,15.466167999999998,0.0 75.019924,15.466252,0.0 75.019944,15.466378000000002,0.0 75.019965,15.466536999999997,0.0 75.019976,15.466635999999994,0.0 75.020012,15.466947000000003,0.0 75.020028,15.467083,0.0 75.020282,15.467033000000002,0.0 75.020654,15.46696,0.0 75.020722,15.466947000000003,0.0 75.020941,15.467087,0.0 75.021225,15.467269999999996,0.0 75.021411,15.467389000000002,0.0 75.021651,15.467497,0.0 75.021922,15.467617,0.0 75.022211,15.467719000000002,0.0 75.022526,15.467833999999996,0.0 75.022696,15.467896,0.0 75.022909,15.468051000000004,0.0 75.023152,15.468224999999997,0.0 75.023321,15.468343999999998,0.0 75.023598,15.468437000000002,0.0 75.023915,15.468544999999999,0.0 75.024174,15.468661000000003,0.0 75.024516,15.468807000000002,0.0 75.024832,15.468939,0.0 75.024938,15.468983,0.0 75.02519600000001,15.469056,0.0 75.025543,15.469156999999997,0.0 75.025901,15.469264000000004,0.0 75.02618,15.469345999999998,0.0 75.02649,15.469437999999998,0.0</coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

i want to read the coordinates from above kml file and store it in a array using php. and then using that array i want to store latitude and longitude separately . given a latitude and longitude point as input i have to find if that belongs to particular place mark.

what i thought is if i am able to read coordinates i have got a code which tells weather the point belongs to the polygon or not the code is:

```
<?php
//Point-In-Polygon Algorithm
$polySides  = 4; //how many corners the polygon has
$polyX    =  array(4,9,11,2);//horizontal coordinates of corners
$polyY    =  array(10,7,2,2);//vertical coordinates of corners
$x = 4;
$y = 10.5;//Outside
//$y = 3.5;//Inside

function pointInPolygon($polySides,$polyX,$polyY,$x,$y) {
  $j = $polySides-1 ;
  $oddNodes = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i<$polySides; $i++) {
    if ($polyY[$i]<$y && $polyY[$j]>=$y 
 ||  $polyY[$j]<$y && $polyY[$i]>=$y) {
    if ($polyX[$i]+($y-$polyY[$i])/($polyY[$j]-$polyY[$i])*($polyX[$j]-$polyX[$i])<$x)    {
    $oddNodes=!$oddNodes; }}
   $j=$i; }

  return $oddNodes; }


 if (pointInPolygon($polySides,$polyX,$polyY,$x,$y)){
  echo "Is in polygon!";
}
else echo "Is not in polygon";
?>
```

please tell me weather this approach is correct or are there any API's which read kml file and give output as to which placemark the given (input) latitude and longitude belongs..

Comment: [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) is what you are looking for.

Comment: What coordinates? All the coordinates tags or the value tags too?

Comment: ya only coordinates in <polygon>

Answer (score 2):

I presume they are x,y coordinates stored in the string `$kml`:

```
$doc   = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $kml );
$coordinates = array();
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'coordinates' ) as $coord ) {
    foreach( explode( ' ', $coord->nodeValue ) as $c ) {
        list( $x, $y ) = explode( ',', $c );
        $t = new StdClass;
        $t->x = $x;
        $t->y = $y;
        $coordinates[] = $t;
    }
}

var_dump( $coordinates );
// First x is $coordinates[0]->x
// First y is $coordinates[0]->y
```

The coordinates are stored in the array `$coordinates` as objects. Read them like this `echo "x:" . $coordinates[0]->x . " y:" . $coordinates[0]->y . "<br>";`

**Edit** This is for placemarks:

```
$doc   = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $kml );
$placemark = array();

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'Placemark' ) as $place ) {
    $coordinates = array();
    foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'coordinates' ) as $coord ) {
        foreach( explode( ' ', $coord->nodeValue ) as $c ) {
            list( $x, $y ) = explode( ',', $c );
            $t = new StdClass;
            $t->x = $x;
            $t->y = $y;
            $coordinates[] = $t;
        }
    }
    $placemark[] = $coordinates;
}

var_dump( $placemark );
// First placemarks first x is $placemark[0][0]->x
// First placemarks first y is $placemark[0][0]->y
```

Answer (score 0):

With my comment in mind, you could use the following code as a starting point:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
echo $xml->Document->Placemark->Polygon->outerBoundaryIs->LinearRing->coordinates->__toString();
```

Depending on what you then want to do with the coordinates, you could use `explode()`.

**EDIT:** To retrieve all coordinates, you will have to loop over them, like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
foreach ($xml->Document->Placemark as $placemark) {
    $coordinates = $placemark->Polygon->outerBoundaryIs->LinearRing->coordinates->__toString();
    echo $coordinates; // gives out the actual coordinates
}
```

Comment: mainly what i want to do is given latitude and longitude i want to find to which <Placemarks> it belongs??

Comment: this was very helpful but if you can tell me how can i read coordinates from all placemarks it will be very much helpful. i tried Document->Placemarks[0] , Document->Placemarks[1]. but if i try to use a loop like Document->Placemarks[$k] where $k lies from 0 to 67, it is not working. please help........

Comment: @Navaneet Please see my updated answer with a `foreach` loop.